# How to get response headers authorization in jquery ajax success?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm setting encrypted username and password authorization in fron end and getting request header response bearer authorization from server. In ajax i'm getting to get that response header in safari correctly but in chrome and firefox its like a null. The problem only in chrome and firefox to get bearer token. How to fix that issues?

Ajax code,

```
$.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:url,
            dataType: "json",
            async:false,
            headers:{ 
                'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa(useremail+":"+password)
            },
            data:'{"datas"}',
            success: function (data, status, request, xhr){
                alert(request.getResponseHeader('Authorization'));
            }
```

[image]

Comment: Is is a cross domain request? Any specific reasons why you're setting ```async: false``` ?

Comment: @fabio.sussetto Yes. this is cross domain request. there is no specific reason for async false.

Comment: Then you should remove async: false : "Setting this option to false (and thus making the call no longer asynchronous) is strongly discouraged, as it can cause the browser to become unresponsive."

Answer (score 1):

Note that as of jQuery 1.8 `async` option is deprecated.

As to why this probably happens:

> During a CORS request, the getResponseHeader() method can only access
>   simple response headers. Simple response headers are defined as
>   follows:
>
> - Cache-Control
> - Content-Language
> - Content-Type
> - Expires
> - Last-Modified
> - Pragma

And as for the solution:

> If you want clients to be able to access other headers, you have to
>   use the Access-Control-Expose-Headers header. The value of this header
>   is a comma-delimited list of response headers you want to expose to
>   the client.

Source: https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/cors/

Comment: Does the `getResponseHeader` still returns null on firefox/chrome after adding the `Access-Control-Expose-Headers` header?

Comment: Yes. still i'm getting null only.

Comment: Check you haven't disabled CORS in Safari: the option is under the Develop menu.

Comment: @Sathya Do you see the server response of this request on Chrome/Firefox in developer's tools? Is the request been made? Is the response returned? Did you add the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header to allow CORS?

Comment: @biphobe yes i'm getting response on developer tools. You can see the attached image on my question.

Comment: @biphobe yes i'm getting response on developer tools. You can see the attached image on my question. that response i got from chrome developer tool

Comment: @Sathya I can't replicate your issue, I tried making $.ajax request just like yours and the custom headers I passed on are available via `getResponseHeader`. Which jQuery version do you use? What's the output if you replace `getResponseHeader('Authorization')` with `getAllResponseHeaders()`?

Answer (score 0):

With reference from this articel : http://osric.com/chris/accidental-developer/2014/08/using-getresponseheader-with-jquerys-ajax-method/

Try with `done` function as shown in the example in the article :

```
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:url,
    dataType: "json",
    async:false,
    headers:{ 
        'Authorization':'Basic '+btoa(useremail+":"+password)
    },
    data:'{"datas"}',
}).done(function (data, textStatus, xhr) { 
    console.log(xhr.getResponseHeader('Authorization')); 
});
```

Comment: The `xhr` object that you're suggesting the OP to use is **the same object** as the `request` that he currently uses in his success callback.

Answer (score 0):

try this..

```
    var settings = {
    "crossDomain": true,
    "url": url,
    "method": "POST",
    "headers": {
     "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
     "Authorization":"Basic "+btoa(useremail+":"+password)
    },
   "data": {
   "name": "name"
  }
 }

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (data,status, xhr) {
     console.log("Authorization=> "+xhr.getResponseHeader('Authorization'));
 });
```